# Ionic Vue and AR.js

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, augmented-reality, ar.js

So i have initiated a project with **Ionic Vue** and I would like to know how can i implement `AR.js` into it. I have tried creating a simple html file containing the code of importing and then put an `iframe` into the `ion-content` of the **Home.vue** file but nothing

Comment: I don't know nothing about Ionic Vue but we are working on the AR.js npm package, maybe this issue may help you https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/234 , read about the Vue example by @thauska.

Comment: I made it work with the way that i mention above, creating an iframe and having an html file as src so all good. But an npm package will be very useful indeed.